# bash—Return status from function in background

Tags: bash, subshell

I have a bash script with roughly the following structure:

```
function download {
    # download a big file
}

function prepare_stuff {
    # prepare some stuff
}

function process_download {
    # process the downloaded file
}

download & prepare_stuff & wait
process_download
```

The first thing it does is to download a file of several hundred megabytes. While the download is in progress, some other things are prepared in the background. When both of these have finished, the download is processed.

`download` may finish in three different ways:

1. The download failed (e.g. server not reachable)
2. The file was downloaded successfully
3. The file has not changed on the server since the last download

Case 1 is an error condition (in which case the function should return something different from zero), while 2 and 3 are not (i.e. the return value should be zero).

Now, I want `process_download` to skip the actual processing when case 1 or 3 is encountered, so I need to pass some kind of status back from `download`. Since `download` runs in a subshell, a variable will not work (assignments take place in the subshell and are not passed back to the parent shell).

How can I pass some kind of value from a function in a subshell back to the parent shell?

Comment: It all comes down to the tools used in the function, i.e. more specifically the exit-code of the last command executed in the function.

Comment: Do you already have a way to test for condition 3, or are you looking on feedback for this?

Comment: @Fred The download function can identify all three conditions.

Comment: So you only need to check for non-zero return code from the download for both conditions that would require bypassing the final processing?

Comment: Not as I’d originally intended it (an unchanged file would have returned zero, just like a successful download, while a failed download would have returned an error code), but that’s what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something similar to what Fred suggested.

First of all, I abandoned the idea of “file not changed on server = no error” and now use the return code simply to express whether we have a download to process—0 if a new file was downloaded, 1 if the download failed or there were no changes. It’s much simpler to handle that way.

Then:

```
function download {
    # download a big file
    # return nonzero if download failed
    # else return nonzero if file has not changed
    # else return 0 (download successful, file has changed)
}

function prepare_stuff {
    # prepare some stuff
}

function process_download {
    # process the downloaded file
}

download &
PID_DOWNLOAD=$!
prepare_stuff &
PID_PREPARE_STUFF=$!
wait $PID_PREPARE_STUFF
wait $PID_DOWNLOAD && process_download || echo "Nothing to process."
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
download &
download_pid=$!
prepare_stuff &
prepare_pid=$!
result=0
wait $download_pid || result=$?
wait $prepare_pid
```

Then, `result` will contain the return code of your previous download command, and both background jobs will be finished, and you can do something like :

```
[[ $result = 0 ]] || process_download
```

With clarifications regarding your third condition, I could make the answer more complete.

Comment: I know, I misread the question first.  I updated my answer.  That being said, I am unclear as to if the OP wants a suggestion to check for condition 3 or not, so my updated proposal does not handle that at this point.

Comment: @codeforester It does.  The `prepare_stuff` function is called while the download is being performed in the background.  The `wait` commands, which cause the script to block, happen when both functions are running in parallel.

Comment: Can there be a situation where download process finishes even before we could wait for it?  In such a case, `wait` is going to fail because of wrong pid.  So, it does seem that we should run download in a subshell.  I deleted my answer because `$!` wasn't set after `{ }` may be because of `&&`.

Comment: @codeforester  It will work.  Processes status remains available after they terminate.  Try `true & { sleep 2 ; wait $! ; }` to see it in action in a trivial case.

Comment: Just tested that: I simulated running time with `sleep` and inserted an even longer `sleep` before the first `wait`—works just as well, even if the function has finished by the time we get to `wait` for it.

Comment: If it did not work, honestly the `wait` would be basically useless for lack of reliability.